# How to draw top down tree chart of following

Tags: charts

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      

\title{Brief Article}


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For drawing trees the `forest` package is very handy:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, minimum size=0.5ex, fill, outer sep=0pt,
% tree style
    grow = east,
    forked edge,        
    s sep = 2mm, 
    l sep = 8mm,  
 fork sep = 4mm,
            }        
[, label=left:\textbf{ISO\slash IEC 29100:2011} 
    [, label=right:Consent and Choice]
    [, label=right:Purpose Legitimacy and Specification]
    [, label=right:Collection Limitation]
    [, label=right:Data Minimization]
    [, label=right:{Use, Retention and Disclosure Limitationg}]
    [, label=right:Accuracy and Quality]
    [, label=right:{Openness, Transparency and Notice}]
    [, label=right:Individual Participation and Access]
    [, label=right:Accountability]
    [, label=right:Information Security Controls]
    [, label=right:Compliance]
 ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum:**
enabling to manually split text in nodes labels by defining style for them. For use two line labels you need increase distance between nodes (dots in diagram)Its use a little bit make diagram's code shorter:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, minimum size=0.5ex, fill, outer sep=0pt,
% tree style
    grow = east,
    forked edge,
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 8mm,
 fork sep = 4mm,
lr/.style = {label={[align=left,    % <--- added
                     font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]right:{#1}}}
            }
[, label=left:\textbf{ISO\slash IEC 29100:2011}
    [, lr=Consent and Choice]
    [, lr=Purpose Legitimacy and Specification]
    [, lr=Collection Limitation]
    [, lr=Data Minimization]
    [, lr={Use, Retention and Disclosure\\ Limitationg}]
    [, lr=Accuracy and Quality]
    [, lr={Openness, Transparency and Notice}]
    [, lr=Individual Participation and Access]
    [, lr=Accountability]
    [, lr=Information Security Controls]
    [, lr=Compliance]
 ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Very nice! Amazing how easy it is to create nice output with a relatively clean input in cases where the desired output is in alignment with the intended use of the package For me, the trouble begins when I have special wishes and I often regret it :).

Comment: Thx, much obliged

Comment: @MuhammadSharjeelZareen, you receive two answers which solve your problem. Now is time that you accept the one of them, which you the most liked by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of the selected answer. When you will have enough reputation, you can upvote bot instead to saying *thank you* ...

Comment: How to wrap the test like"Use, Retention and Disclosure Limitation" as it is going out for margin ?

Comment: @MuhammadSharjeelZareen, three possibilities: (i) reduce `l sep` and `
 fork sep`, (ii) reduce font size, (iii) preferable, enable splet this text in two column by adding `align=left` to label option, see addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty in Ti*k*Z:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw (0,0)    circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=east, xshift=-0.5ex] {\strut\bfseries ISO\slash IEC 29100:2011};
\filldraw (2,2.5)  circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Consent and Choice};
\filldraw (2,2)    circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Purpose Legitimacy and Specification};
\filldraw (2,1.5)  circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Collection Limitation};
\filldraw (2,1)    circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Data Minimization};
\filldraw (2,0.5)  circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Use, Retention and Disclosure Limitation};
\filldraw (2,0)    circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Accuracy and Quality};
\filldraw (2,-0.5) circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Openness, Transparency and Notice};
\filldraw (2,-1)   circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Individual Participation and Access};
\filldraw (2,-1.5) circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Accountability};
\filldraw (2,-2)   circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Information Security Controls};
\filldraw (2,-2.5) circle[radius=0.5ex] node [anchor=west, xshift=0.5ex]  {\strut Compliance};
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw (1,-2.5) -- +(0,5);
\foreach \n in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} {\draw (1,\n) -- +(1,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, much obliged

Comment: How to wrap the test like"Use, Retention and Disclosure Limitation" as it is going out for margin ?

Comment: @MuhammadSharjeelZareen `makecell` is your friend