# forest - Put the parent nodes at the top level

Tags: nodes, forest

With the code below, I would like to put the parent nodes at the top. Is it feasible?

[image]

```
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593383/6880

\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, minimum size=0.5ex, fill, outer sep=0pt,
% tree style
    grow = east,
    forked edge,
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 8mm,
 fork sep = 4mm,
lr/.style = {label={[align=left,    % <--- added
                     font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]right:{#1}}}
            }
[, label=left:\textbf{ISO\slash IEC 29100:2011}
    [, lr=Consent and Choice]
    [, lr=Purpose Legitimacy and Specification]
    [, lr=Collection Limitation]
    [, lr=Data Minimization]
    [, lr={Use, Retention and Disclosure\\ Limitationg}]
    [, lr=Accuracy and Quality]
    [, lr={Openness, Transparency and Notice}]
    [, lr=Individual Participation and Access]
    [, lr=Accountability]
    [, lr=Information Security Controls]
    [, lr=Compliance]
 ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `calign=last` option results in the following output:

[image]

Alternatively `calign=first, reversed=true` also works.

---

```
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593383/6880

\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    circle, minimum size=0.5ex, fill, outer sep=0pt,
% tree style
    grow = east,
    calign=last, %<------------------------- added
    forked edge,
    s sep = 4mm,
    l sep = 8mm,
 fork sep = 4mm,
lr/.style = {label={[align=left,    % <--- added
                     font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]right:{#1}}}
            }
[, label=left:\textbf{ISO\slash IEC 29100:2011}
    [, lr=Consent and Choice]
    [, lr=Purpose Legitimacy and Specification]
    [, lr=Collection Limitation]
    [, lr=Data Minimization]
    [, lr={Use, Retention and Disclosure\\ Limitationg}]
    [, lr=Accuracy and Quality]
    [, lr={Openness, Transparency and Notice}]
    [, lr=Individual Participation and Access]
    [, lr=Accountability]
    [, lr=Information Security Controls]
    [, lr=Compliance]
 ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple. Why I don't read the f------ manual... Thanks a lot!